# error in returning value for c# method

Tags: c#, asp.net, methods

I am having my expected value with the below codes which is working fine.

```
List<int> member_spill = new List<int>();
string query1 = "select xyz from spill_donation where reg=148";
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS)) {
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query1, con);
    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
        while (reader.Read()) {
            if (!reader.IsDBNull(0)) {  
                member_spill.Add(Convert.ToInt32(reader["xyz"]));
            }
        }
    }        
    foreach (int empty_spill in member_spill) {
        long parentid;
        Boolean isTrue = false;
        int spilled_id = empty_spill;
        query="select a.reflection1,a.reflection2 from table_1 a, table_2 b where a.reg = b.xyz and b.xyz="+spilled_id;
        DataTable dtspillresult = objDUT.GetDataTable(query);
        if (dtspillresult.Rows.Count!=0) {
            if(Convert.ToInt32(dtspillresult.Rows[0]["reflection1"]) == 0 && Convert.ToInt32(dtspillresult.Rows[0]["reflection2"]) == 0) {
                isTrue=true;
            }
            if(Convert.ToInt32(dtspillresult.Rows[0]["reflection1"]) == 1 && Convert.ToInt32(dtspillresult.Rows[0]["reflection2"]) == 0) {
                isTrue=true;
            }
            if(Convert.ToInt32(dtspillresult.Rows[0]["reflection1"]) == 0 && Convert.ToInt32(dtspillresult.Rows[0]["reflection2"]) == 1) {
                isTrue=true;
            }
            if (isTrue==true) {
                parentid = Convert.ToInt64(dtspillresult.Rows[0]["reg"]);
                Label10.Text = parentid.ToString();
                break;
            }
        }                 
    }
}
```

when i am trying to make it a method that returns a value, it shows an error.I am new to c#.net and so please ignore my mistakes.Thanks in Advance for suggestions to solve the issues.

```
    private long parentid(long sponsorid) {
        long parent_id;
        List<int> member_spill = new List<int>();
        string query1 = "select xyz from spill_donation where reg=148";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS)) {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query1, con);
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
                while (reader.Read()) {
                    if (!reader.IsDBNull(0)) {
                        member_spill.Add(Convert.ToInt32( reader["xyz"] ));
                    }
                }
            }
            foreach (int empty_spill in member_spill) {
                Boolean isTrue = false;
                int spilled_id = empty_spill;
                query="select a.reflection1,a.reflection2 from table_1 a, table_2 b where a.reg = b.xyz and b.xyz="+spilled_id;
                DataTable dtspillresult = objDUT.GetDataTable(query);
                if (dtspillresult.Rows.Count!=0) {
                    if(Convert.ToInt32(dtspillresult.Rows[0]["reflection1"]) == 0 && Convert.ToInt32(dtspillresult.Rows[0]["reflection2"]) == 0) {
                        isTrue=true;
                    }
                    if(Convert.ToInt32(dtspillresult.Rows[0]["reflection1"]) == 1 && Convert.ToInt32(dtspillresult.Rows[0]["reflection2"]) == 0) {
                        isTrue=true;
                    }
                    if(Convert.ToInt32(dtspillresult.Rows[0]["reflection1"]) == 0 && Convert.ToInt32(dtspillresult.Rows[0]["reflection2"]) == 1) {
                        isTrue=true;
                    }

                    if (isTrue==true) {
                        parentid = Convert.ToInt64(dtspillresult.Rows[0]["reg"]);
                        break;
                    }
                }                 
            }
        }
        return parent_id;
    }
```

when i am trying to make it a method that returns a value, it shows an error.I am new to c#.net and so please ignore my mistakes.Thanks in Advance for suggestions to solve the issues.

Comment: Care to post the error message and tell us on what line did you see it?

Comment: OK I think I have seen it. What happens when your code never sets _isTrue_ or there are no rows in the datatable _dtspillresult_ ? The variable _parent_id_ is never set to a value. You need to initialize it when you declare it _int parent_id = 0;_ However next time provide the informations about the error messages received

Comment: thank you all. I got the solution and it is working.

Answer (score 1):

In the method, `parent_id` is not guaranteed to have a value as the method is currently written. The only time `parent_id` is assigned a value is based on some conditions.

To resolve the compile error, assign a default value:

```
private long parentid(long sponsorid) 
{
  long parent_id = 0; // or some other value.
  // other code that conditionally assigns the value.
  return parent_id;
}
```

A typical pattern in this scenario, if the value is not guaranteed to exist in the method, is to use an out parameter and a bool return value for the method.

```
long parentId;
if(TryGetParentId(sponsorid, out parentId)
{
  // parentId will now have a value
  // do work when there is a parentId
}
```

The method would then look something along the lines of:

```
private bool TryGetParentId(long sponsorid, out long parentid) 
{
  // perform work to get the parentid
  foreach(x in y)
  {
      parentid = 99; // actual value would be assigned with your logic
      return true;
  }

  // no value was found. assign a default value to the 
  // out param of parentid; required for compiler.
  parentid = 0;

  return false;
}
```

Comment: @BanglaTiger - welcome to StackOverflow. If this answer helped you, give it an upvote and accept the answer. Cheers!